# Как отрисовать объект с использованием буфера глубины, но без записи в него?

Tags: 3d, directx

Требуется отрендерить объект, причем он должен учитывать буфер глубины (т.е. не перекрывать ближние объекты и перекрывать дальние), но при этом не менять значения в буфере глубины. Интересует для DirectX (10 или 11).

Т.е. нужно то самое, что в OpenGL делает:

```
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
```

Comment: Ответы желательно писать в поле для ответов, чтобы вопрос не выглядел неотвеченным.

Answer (score 3):

Все, разобрался. Нужно использовать флаг `D3D10_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ZERO`, сбило с толку его название - выглядит так, как будто он включает режим записи нулей.